# Sencha Touch - Titlebar to be multi-line text (2 lines)

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to have a titlebar with two lines of text in the middle rather than the 1 big text.

So it will look something like:

```
<Back] Registration [Support]
         Step 1/5
```

Basically, instead of the one big text. I want the top line to be small and the bottom line to be bigger. I know frameworks are about making you work faster but it looks like I'm falling at the very first hurdle and I can't see any way of doing something that I could have done in minutes with standard JS/CSS.

I'm guessing I'm going to have to extend this functionality somewhat? I'm using Sencha Architect to try and speed up my work-flow.

Cheers, Dom

Answer (score 1):

Just use the most simple way, like:

```
title: '<span class="first-line">first line</span><br><span class="second-line">second line</span>'
```

then increase the height your titlebar or toolbar, let's say about 200px. I guess you cannot see the second line because the bar's height is not enough.